# My JRadioButton change look with setOpaque(false)

Tags: java, swing, transparent, look-and-feel, jradiobutton

I want to remove the background of my JRadioButton but still keeping the same look & feel.
Images will speak by themselves:

When I do this code:

```
JRadioButton myJRadioButton = new JRadioButton("My JRadioButton");
add(myJRadioButton);
```

I get this:

[image]

And when I run it with this code:

```
JRadioButton myJRadioButton = new JRadioButton("My JRadioButton");
myJRadioButton.setForeground(Color.white); //To see it on the black background.
myJRadioButton.setOpaque(false); 
add(myJRadioButton);
```

I get this:

[image]

I've something like a "star" instead of a great and beautiful circle.
And what I want is to keep the great and beautiful circle of the first image but without the default background according to it.

Comment: To get the circle instead of the star, you could decompile the class that has the radio button, and then copy the `paint()` code to a class that overrides your radio button. Then you can remove that part of the circle.

Comment: I'm not sure to have totally understand what you suggest but I'll try what I think I've understood ^^ Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class which extends the JRadioButton and add all the properties inside the class:

```
        setOpaque(false);
        setContentAreaFilled(false);
        setBorderPainted(false);
        setForeground(Color.white);
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);
```

### Sample output:

[image: picture]

### Code:

```
public class Sample extends JPanel {

    public Sample() {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        TransparentButton testButton = new TransparentButton("hello");
        testButton.setSelected(true);

        add(testButton, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello Word demo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JComponent newContentPane = new Sample();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true);
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    class TransparentButton extends JRadioButton {
        public TransparentButton(String string) {
            super(string);
            setOpaque(false);
            setContentAreaFilled(false);
            setBorderPainted(false);
            setForeground(Color.white);
            setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank's, this is not exactly like the setOpaque(true) look & feel but this is fine for me. :)

Answer (score 2):

Document says

```
public void setOpaque(boolean isOpaque)
```

> If true the component paints every pixel within its bounds. Otherwise,
>   the component may not paint some or all of its pixels, allowing the
>   underlying pixels to show through. The default value of this property
>   is false for JComponent. However, the default value for this property
>   on most standard JComponent subclasses (such as JButton and JTree) is
>   look-and-feel dependent.

It says all.

Comment: Yes but is there any way to restore the default look & feel even with setOpaque(false)?